# Black Scholes implied volatility

Tags: volatility, black-scholes, implied-volatility, no-arbitrage-theory

I am reading up on implied volatility and I encountered the term *Black-Scholes implied volatility* which I haven't heard before. What is the meaning of this term?

Say I am looking at the Heston model whose implied volatility we know. Does *Black-Scholes implied volatility* mean that I can use this value for the implied volatility in the BS-equation? If yes, what do we get from this mixture?

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+is+implied+volatility